# C++ Vector<int> array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl, initialization

Given the following code:

```
vector<int> A[1000000];
for( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ ){
    A[i].clear();
}
```

I am running it on an automated terminal that has test cases run with my code, so I can't get full debug messages. I don't get any errors, and the program seems to run fine with single test cases. However when I run against the full set I pass/fail test cases *randomly* (one time I may pass the first 3, another I pass everything but them, another I only pass the second, etc). I want to make sure this kind of initialization would get rid of "undefined" values on the array (eg `char *buffer = new char[100]; buffer[0] = 0;`) so that it is not a cause of random crashes.

`sizeof(A) == 24000000` (~23MB), `sizeof(int) == 4`. I only add up to 1 million integers to these vectors (in total), so in the worst tests, each vector could be a one element vector, or a single vector could have 1 million integers, while the rest remains empty.

Do I have to call a destructor? I assumed not since I never called new, but I'm new to STL. Finally it could be not an issue with my code but the tester, but still, want to make sure this is fine on my side.

Comment: This code is OK, there could be a bug elsewhere. Or a stack overflow

Comment: Have you tried, `vector<int> A(1000000,0);`?  This will fill the vector with zeros.

Comment: @tinstaafl that is a single vector, OP code makes a million vectors (which I assume is intentional)

Comment: check for sizeof(int) in your compiler, if it's 2 byte then the for loop is culprit.

Comment: @M.M Yes. it is 1 million vectors (that will hold 1 million ints between all of them, so that shouldnt be the cause of an out of memory), not a single 1 million element vector sadly. I'll guess its the tester code then...

Comment: @VivekD weird enough, it couts 4

Comment: To answer the only question you asked, no it is not necessary to call a destructor.  When `A` ceases to exist, the destructors for all `1000000` elements (each an `std::vector<int>`) will be called.    The reason it fails test cases, however, is completely unrelated to that - colloquially, your program is exhausting available stack space.     If you are using a million vectors that, in total, contain no more than a million integers, then you need to find a better implementation strategy - you're consuming large amounts of (stack space) memory without good reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a stack overflow, as M.M suggested. The line

```
std::vector<int> A[1000000];
```

creates a million vector objects on the stack, which is too much. On my machine, the example failed for one million vectors, but it worked fine for one thousand.

Comment: Are you sure? sizeof(A) returns 24000000 to me, thats only 23MB I will only add 1 million integers to these vectors (in total), so each vector could be a one element vector, or a single vector could have 1 million, while the rest remains empty.

Comment: Default stack size in the Visual Studio for example is 1 MB. Create your array of vectors on the heap using `new` operator instead.

Comment: don't use `new`  ... vector of vectors, or `unique_ptr` of vector array would both be preferable

Comment: 23MB is **certainly** too big for the stack, so you have to allocate on the heap. I would try to avoid using `new` in this case. Instead, you could use a vector of vectors: `std::vector<std::vector<int> > A(1000000);`.

Comment: @cthl well it is possible to modify stack size to be in the gigabytes. Seems likely to exceed common compilers' default stack size though.

Comment: still failing randomly sadly, I set it to 512mb, and i did change everything to vectors

Comment: How did you increase the stack size? Are you sure it worked? In either case, this is not a practical solution, since you use very compiler specific features where they are not necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

In place of for loop use below code

```
std::fill(A.begin(), A.end(), 0);
```